# How to connect a bubble.io app with Datastax AstraDB?

Tags: datastax, bubble.io, astradb

I am trying to connect to my DataStax AstraDB using a Bubble.io app.  I am not able to do so, can someone please help me figure this out?  I read through the docs and I could not find anything.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question. I am seeing [an HTTP request/raw API plugin availability with Bubble.io](https://bubble.io/plugin/http---request--response--raw-api-1627331533987x557103354140688400) that could be used here with [Astra DB's Data APIs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/develop/developing.html) to [fetch data from an external API](https://manual.bubble.io/core-resources/data/data-sources#get-data-from-an-external-api).

Please be aware that, [according to Bubble's documentation, I'm seeing the following API connector hard limit](https://manual.bubble.io/help-guides/maintaining-an-application/performance-and-scaling/hard-limits#api-connector-responses),

> *There's a hard limit of 50 MB for responses to an outgoing API call made with the API Connector or a plugin. Exceeding the limit will generate an error in the logs: "response too large".*

My bubble API Connector will look like this and I can use it as *Data* / *Action* as per my needs:
[image]